# IPP QBO UK v3 - Trouble adding Journal Entry with TaxCodeRef

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Trying to get a journal entry to save in QBO UK using TaxCodeRef but keep getting the same error message back. I have set the TaxApplicableOn correctly. I did a query of a manually entered journal entry and it shows the element TaxAmount however I don't know this value at runtime. How can I get a journal entry to save when setting a TaxCodeRef?

Here's my XML request and response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<outgoing><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <JournalEntry xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <TxnDate>2014-03-05</TxnDate>
    <PrivateNote>Invoice</PrivateNote>
    <DocNumber>102</DocNumber>
    <Adjustment>false</Adjustment>
    <Line>
      <Desc>Credit Sales</Desc>
      <Amount>150</Amount>
      <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
      <JournalEntryLineDetail>
        <PostingType>Credit</PostingType>
        <AccountRef>1</AccountRef>
        <ClassRef></ClassRef>
        <DepartmentRef></DepartmentRef>
        <BillableStatus></BillableStatus>
        <TaxCodeRef>3</TaxCodeRef>
        <TaxApplicableOn>Credit</TaxApplicableOn>
      </JournalEntryLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <Desc>Debit Accounts Receivable</Desc>
      <Amount>150.00</Amount>
      <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
      <JournalEntryLineDetail>
        <PostingType>Debit</PostingType>
        <Entity>
          <Type>Customer</Type>
          <EntityRef>21</EntityRef>
        </Entity>
        <AccountRef>52</AccountRef>
        <ClassRef></ClassRef>
        <DepartmentRef></DepartmentRef>
        <BillableStatus></BillableStatus>
        <TaxCodeRef>3</TaxCodeRef>
        <TaxApplicableOn>Debit</TaxApplicableOn>
      </JournalEntryLineDetail>
    </Line>
  </JournalEntry>
</outgoing>
<returns><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-03-17T07:21:39.545-07:00">
    <Fault type="ValidationFault">
      <Error code="2270" element="TaxApplicableOn">
        <Message>TaxApplicableon missing or invalid</Message>
        <Detail>TaxApplicableOn null is required and valid values are Credit or Debit</Detail>
      </Error>
      <Error code="2270" element="TaxApplicableOn">
        <Message>TaxApplicableon missing or invalid</Message>
        <Detail>TaxApplicableOn null is required and valid values are Credit or Debit</Detail>
      </Error>
    </Fault>
  </IntuitResponse>
</returns>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a Journal Entry from QBO UI and selected Sales Check box on the line item.
Here is the response.
Looks like the error message is wrong. Valid value is Sales or Purchase(if Sales box is not selected). Let me get some more details around this.

```
<JournalEntry domain="QBO" sparse="false">
  <Id>29</Id>
  <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
  <MetaData>
    <CreateTime>2014-03-17T22:29:18-07:00</CreateTime>
    <LastUpdatedTime>2014-03-17T22:29:18-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
  </MetaData>
  <DocNumber>DocNu2</DocNumber>
  <TxnDate>2014-03-18</TxnDate>
  <CurrencyRef name="British Pound Sterling">GBP</CurrencyRef>
  <ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
  <Line>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Description>ff</Description>
    <Amount>24.00</Amount>
    <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
    <JournalEntryLineDetail>
      <PostingType>Debit</PostingType>
      <Entity>
        <Type>Customer</Type>
        <EntityRef name="toto">1</EntityRef>
      </Entity>
      <AccountRef name="Debtors">50</AccountRef>
      <TaxCodeRef>3</TaxCodeRef>
      <TaxApplicableOn>Sales</TaxApplicableOn>
      <TaxAmount>4.80</TaxAmount>
    </JournalEntryLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Description>ff</Description>
    <Amount>28.80</Amount>
    <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
    <JournalEntryLineDetail>
      <PostingType>Credit</PostingType>
      <Entity>
        <Type>Customer</Type>
        <EntityRef name="toto">1</EntityRef>
      </Entity>
      <AccountRef name="Savings">59</AccountRef>
      <TaxCodeRef>9</TaxCodeRef>
      <TaxApplicableOn>Sales</TaxApplicableOn>
      <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
    </JournalEntryLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <TxnTaxDetail>
    <TaxLine>
      <Amount>4.80</Amount>
      <DetailType>TaxLineDetail</DetailType>
      <TaxLineDetail>
        <TaxRateRef>4</TaxRateRef>
        <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
        <TaxPercent>20</TaxPercent>
        <NetAmountTaxable>24.00</NetAmountTaxable>
      </TaxLineDetail>
    </TaxLine>
    <TaxLine>
      <Amount>0</Amount>
      <DetailType>TaxLineDetail</DetailType>
      <TaxLineDetail>
        <TaxRateRef>15</TaxRateRef>
        <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
        <TaxPercent>0</TaxPercent>
        <NetAmountTaxable>-28.80</NetAmountTaxable>
      </TaxLineDetail>
    </TaxLine>
  </TxnTaxDetail>
  <Adjustment>false</Adjustment>
</JournalEntry>
```

I see that the docs here-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/journalentry

mention that it is a type of TaxApplicableOnEnum which has valid values as sales or purchase.

Comment: I will raise a bug for this.

Comment: What's the easiest way at runtime to determine if the TaxApplicableOn status is sales or purchase?

Comment: If it is set on the QBO UI, then when do a Read call, you will get it's value in the TaxApplicableOn property. If you are doing a create then you need to set its value to the enum type as mentioned above.

Comment: Nimisha - I know how to set the value, what I am asking is how do I determine if the TaxApplicableOn should be set to Sales or Purchase when creating the journal entry?